# How to to print nth from end in java

Tags: java

Write a program that stores a list of positive integers from input into an array and outputs the Nth number from the end of the array. A negative integer indicates the end of the input and is not stored in the array. Convert the last negative integer to positive and use as N. Output the last integer (as negative) if the size of the array is smaller than N. Assume the array will always contain fewer than 20 integers

```
`import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[20];   // List of integers from input
      int neg = 0;
      int n = 0;
      int printValue = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < userValues.length && scnr.hasNextInt(); i++) {
      userValues[i]  = scnr.nextInt();  
      
      if (userValues[i]< 0){
         neg = userValues[i];
          printValue = i-neg;
          if( neg>i){
          System.out.println(neg);
         }
      else if ( neg < i) {
         System.out.println(userValues[printValue]);
      }
      
   }
   }
}
}   `
```

I believe that there's something wrong with the way I'm assigning the printValue variable but I don't know why, when I print the printValue variable without the userValues array it does weird things:
Input
1 5 9 7 5 -3
Your output
8
Expected output
9
OR
Input
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 -1
Your output
12
Expected output
14

Otherwise if I print userValues[printValue] the only output I receive is 0

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: what happens if `userValues[i]<0`, `neg=userValues[i]` and then `printValue=i-neg`? Yes, printValue is bigger than i, which means it points to some value beyond your input. Check the signs in your calculation.

Comment: `System.out.println(userValues[printValue])` - what do you calculate the value of `printValue` to be? Is this a valid element of the array?

Comment: "A negative integer indicates the end of the input and is not stored in the array." Currently, you're putting all values into the array BEFORE you've determined that it's negative.

Comment: I would separate printing the results from gathering the input. So, in your loop, just test for a negative number: if not negative, save input from the scanner to the array; if negative, save that value to `neg` and break out of the loop. Then you can construct the output based on your requirements. Also, remember to close the scanner after you exit the scanning loop.